# Would you stop using Stack Exchange if it were taken over by a big internet company (e.g. Google)?

Tags: discussion, polling

At first I wanted to make this an actual poll (Yes, No, Maybe), but apparently, polls [are not well received here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233908/are-poll-style-questions-ever-acceptable-on-meta-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1). So, let's see what an extended discussion+voting yields.

Based on a [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298770/what-could-make-stack-exchange-obsolete) I asked, two answers highlighted that what could make Stack Exchange Obsolete is being taken over by a giant Internet company (e.g. Google), which transform the users experience with advertising, rigid management style, etc.

Comment: This just isn't an answerable question. This site isn't designed for hypotheticals that may or may not ever occur. Users could not possibly tell you how they'd react because that reaction can only be determined by actually experiencing the situation, and is dependent on the time it occurs, which company, and how policies get changed due to it. Hypothetical questions are just terrible questions in general.

Comment: @animuson still, wrong close reason. This is totally about Stack Exchange. Maybe "Opinion based" fits here. Doesn't really matter though, I guess.

Comment: Anyway, this kind of question fits chat. Find a busy room on SO which isn't purely for programming (i.e. also for other things), with lots of active/veteran SO users, and ask it there.

Comment: @Why are then the following list of questions closed then? [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6480/would-you-play-a-stack-overflow-board-game?rq=1), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39539/would-you-take-a-share-in-stack-overflow?rq=1), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39588/if-stack-overflow-ever-floats-would-we-be-insiders?noredirect=1&lq=1), ...

Comment: @animuson see my previous comment. I find your decision arbitrary.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Censorship from SE at its best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I would quit if I start to see the monetisation of SE via advertisement.

There are already advertisements.

Even the image you see on some tags are sponsored.

[image]

The image with text *IJ* is sponsored.

Second thing

I strongly believe that Joel and team won't sell SE to another company because SE is doing well and not in loss.

Even if they did, My decision to continue will be based on the factors.

1. The moderation (Whether the community can elect mods or mods are appointed by the company.)
2. Whether the company reduce the scope only to technology they are interested (or) getting paid.

In such cases, I will stop using this site.

But as far as I know, the selling of SE to another company will happen only after 6-8 weeks.

Comment: A company does not need to be at loss to be taken over. Probably the opposite is the norm.

Comment: agree but SE is performing good and I strongly believe that they won't sell themself until they are in loss( not sure whether they sell even if they are loss or they may find other ways to make profit)

Comment: Slashdot was still worth reading for some time after they were acquired, but my decision to leave was mostly based on the pop-up ads that started showing up in the news feed. Same type of factors apply to SE.